# Euler characteristic of a subset of cartesian product induced by a group action

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

let $X$ be a CW-complex on which a finite group $G$ acts.
define

$$F=\{ (x,gx)\;|\; x\in X ,g \in G \}$$
i want to compute the Euler characteristic of $F$. I wrote $$F=\cup_{g\in G}{F_g}\;\;,\;\; F_g=\{ (x,gx)\;|\; x\in X  \}$$ and noted that for a given $g\in G$, $F_g$ is a copy of $X$.
In particular, when the action is free, $F$ is a disjoint union of copies of $F_g$ and then 
$\chi(F)=|G| \chi(X)$, but when the action is not free the intersections $F_g\cap F_h$ are not clear. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, where did this question arise?

Comment: I am conjecturing homework...